# ImageView Not Working Without a SetValue

Tags: java, android, firebase, imageview

This may be a stupid question but actually I do not think it is.
I am getting pictures from Firebase and my problem is that I am facing problem to display it without setting a `Number to width or Height`. For instance, I cannot see the image in my phone by using these lines of codes

```
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

or with this one

```
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

However, if I set a real Number to `layout_width or layout_height`, I am able to see the picture. For instance,

```
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="320dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

Anyone can help me to solve it. Why using wrap_content or Match_parent is not working?

Edit: my Current Layout

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
app:cardElevation="2dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/gridViewImagee"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

By the way I am CoordinateLayout which has a Width and height of match_parent. My RecyclerView Item is located here:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewSingleProf"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: can you post your full layout xml?

Comment: the problem might be in the container ViewGroup, which holds your ImageView

Comment: @Marc-AndréTherrien Added

Comment: @VladMatvienko I added the Full Layout.. Take a look again

Comment: is that a ListView or RecyclerView item View?

Comment: @VladMatvienko RecyclerView

Comment: than add the layout where you use recyclerview

Comment: @VladMatvienko Added

Comment: I think that it is because your recyclerView is inside a scrollview. Why do you need it?

Comment: @VladMatvienko I will try to remove that just to see if it changes something. I am using it (`NestedScrollView`) inside my `CoordinatorLayout` so it hides the Menu when scrolling up

Comment: have you tried by applying any scaleType to ImageView? try using scale type centerCrop.

Comment: The problem might be in the way you have built the RecyclerView item layout. Don't make the layout_height of the CardView and LinearLayout ti match parent. Also, remove the NestedScrollView. Give it a try